If Most Of The Apostles Were of Galilee, and Galilee Was Part of "Israel" Not Judah/Judea How Are They Considered Jews/Judeans G2453?
I was going to respond to a question along similar lines I saw here but apparently I don't have a reputation yet so I can't respond..  So, here I am..  I already know the answer better than most who will respond I bet, but I'd like to see what a high reputation can add to the discussion, please bring verse..
Kind regards
P.S. Apparently I can't create new tags without a 300 reputation either..  I better get busy... ha

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Ashkenaz is of Japeth, not Shem..  They should also add laughing clown tag..                                                                    "Today Ashkenazim constitute more than 80 percent of all the Jews in the world, vastly outnumbering Sephardic Jews."
https://www.britannica.com/topic/Ashkenazi
A substantial prehistoric European ancestry amongst Ashkenazi maternal lineages
https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms3543
The Missing Link of Jewish European Ancestry: Contrasting the Rhineland and the Khazarian Hypotheses
https://academic.oup.com/gbe/article/5/1/61/728117

The Origins of Ashkenaz, Ashkenazic Jews, and Yiddish https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5478715/
Scholars Debate Roots of Yiddish, Migration of Jews https://www.nytimes.com/1996/10/29/science/scholars-debate-roots-of-yiddish-migration-of-jews.html
Yiddish evidence for the khazar component in the Ashkenazic Ethnogenesis https://brill.com/display/book/edcoll/9789047421450/Bej.9789004160422.i-460_021.xml
CHAZARS:By: Herman Rosenthal Jewish Encyclopedia
https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4279-chazars

Israel originally consisted of 12 tribes, each being descendants of Jacob's 12 sons.
Well almost.
The Levites formed the priesthood and didn't have their own land, but Joseph received a double portion and so each of his two sons formed a tribe (Manasseh and Ephraim).
After King Solomon, the nation split into two kingdoms, Israel in the north and Judah in the south.
Israel retained the name and birthright blessings of Jacob because it included the tribe of Joseph.
Judah retained the royal line and promise of the Messiah, and also included some of Levi and the remnant of Benjamin.
The people of Judah became known as "Jews", a name that is first used in 2 Kings 16:5, where Israel and Syria are at war against the Jews.
Later, the tribes of the northern kingdom were taken into captivity by the Assyrians, never to return.
The Epistle of James is addressed "to the twelve tribes which are scattered abroad".
Late in the first century, historian Josephus recorded that "the ten tribes are beyond the Euphrates till now, and are an immense multitude and not to be estimated in numbers".
They have since been lost to mainstream history.
Most of the northern kingdom's land became known as Samaria,
while one area, Galilee, was originally part of the lands owned by Asher, Dan, and Naphthali.
Later, most of the Jews were taken into captivity by the Babylonians, but unlike the northern tribes, they eventually returned to resettle Judah and Galilee.
Josephus records that many of the original Iturean inhabitants of Galilee were converted to Judaism by Aristobulus I, who was King of Judea from 104–103 BCE.
During their occupation, the Roman province of Judea included all of Judea and Samaria, but not Galilee, which bordered on the north.

— Judaea Roman Province - Judaea (Roman province) - Wikipedia

Yes well aware of all this, and much more, more like buried from mainstream history by very specific interests..  So, being that there is 0 evidence in scripture to support the belief that most of the Apostles were Judahites/H3064, would it be fair in your opinion to say their identification as "Jews"/Judeans G2453, has to do with outsider coinage?  Also, that it is quite reasonable to speculate that like Paul whose family was from Galilee, they could very easily all have been Benjamites?

@MrSparkums, I suspect that most Israelites remaining in the area had become fully integrated into Judah by this time, regardless of which tribe their ancestors originally belonged to. A few, such as Saul (Paul), did keep track of their tribal ancestry, but that is perhaps because they cared more than most about such distinctions, Saul being a Pharisee. Remember that at one point, the entire tribe of Benjamin had been reduced to 600 males, with most of them finding wives from Manasseh. And Judaism welcomed converts from all nations. Race was a poorly defined concept then (and still is).

Well, race is not a Biblical or scientific concept so that would make it difficult..  The reason I am quite persuaded they were Benjamites is primarily Genesis 35:31-35, 1 Kings 11:36, also that Jerusalem was originally part of the lands appointed to Benjamin Joshua 18:28, Judges 1:21..  So, who would logically play a major role in the Messiah's Earthly ministry?

Also, don't you feel it is misleading to refer to the Faith of the "Hebrew Israelites” as "Judaism", when most of the Israelites were never Jews in any way?  "Judaism" is Babylonian Talmud 2-6th Century, & Kabbalah 11-16th centuries.
“He argued that it is inappropriate to translate the Greek word Ioudaios by the English word “Jew.” Calling Jesus “a Jew,” Malina says, is inherently misleading because it anachronistically defines Jesus according to a religion based on a rabbinic model of the Babylonian Talmud of the 5th-6th centuries.“
https://themarginaliareview.com/judean-jew-jesus-paul/

“Jesus and his earliest followers, evidence demonstrates, were called Israelites', Galileans' or Nazoreans' by their fellow Israelites. Israel', Israelites' were the preferred terms of self-designation among members of the house of Israel when addressing other members—not ''Ιουδαιος'', Jew' or Judaism'. Modern interpreters and translators of the Bible, it is argued, should respect and follow this insider preference. ''Ιουδαιος', , an outsider coinage, is best rendered Judaean', not Jew', to reflect the explicit or implied connection with Judaea.”

From - "Jesus the Israelite Was Neither a Jew' Nor a Christian': On Correcting Misleading Nomenclature"
https://brill.com/view/journals/jshj/5/2/article-p119_3.xml?language=en

My mistake not Gen 35:31, that doesn't exist : )  I meant 1 Kings 11:31-35

You should more explicitly clearly ask for how exactly the Jews and israelites were united and intermixed and became interchangeable terms in history and bible. Though, I have answered that with a great article.
